# Link 2 Jssor sliders together

Tags: jssor

Goodafternoon,

I would like to use 2 different Jssor sliders on the same page where te second slider should react on the selected image on the first slider.

Dos anyone know how to get this working

Comment: what do you mean 'react'?

Answer (score 1):

```
var options = {};

var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);

var options2 = {};

var jssor_slider2 = new $JssorSlider$("slider2_container", options2);

jssor_slider1.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_POSITION_CHANGE, function (position, fromPosition) {
    jssor_slider2.$GoTo(position);
});
```